# How to pass custom props when using React Navigation version 5?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, watermelondb

I have upgraded to `React Navigation v5` in my app. I am using watermelondb in my app.
While using `ReactNavigationv4`, I used to pass the database props as follows

```
export const createNavigation = props =>
```

But in v5 do something as

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator({database});
```

throws an error saying

[image]

Does any one know how to pass props for v5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use React context API to pass your `database` to all screens: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

```js
<DatabaseContext.Provider value={database}>
  <NavigationContainer>
    {/* ... */}
  </NavigationContainer>
</DatabaseContext.Provider>
```

And then in your screens where you need the database, use:

```js
const database = React.useContext(DatabaseContext);
```

Or for class components: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype